# Как из колбека передать переменную во внешний код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

В консоли step равен undefind, а нужно, чтобы сохранялись данные из пришедшего ответа.

```
let step;

$.ajax({
  url: "https://kachay.com.ua/calculation_info.php",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "get",
  success: function(res) {
    step = res.data.sum_step
  }
})
console.log(step)
```

Comment: они и сохраняться, только чуть позже. Если надо прям в следующей строке, то запрос синхронным должен быть, что может приводить к нежелательным эффектам для пользователя

Comment: где-то надо расставить async/await?

Comment: Да,  можно использовать async await

Comment: а где конкретно в примере их надо поставить? Пробую разные варианты и не работает.